# Problem with the multiplication table of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, return

I am trying to write a function that shows me the multiplication table of a number:

```
def tabellina(n):

   for i in range (1,11):

       print(n*i)
```

If I write the function in this way, it works fine.
 If I put 4 instead of n, it prints:

> 4,8,12,16,20,24,28...40

But if I use return instead of print, it does not work anymore, and it just returns me the n value.

I have to use the return and I can’t use the print

What should I do? (I MUST use return NOT print)

Comment: `return` exits the loop, this is why your function will just return the first value.

Comment: Maybe return a list of values?

Comment: I would recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides or tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it returns the n value if you use return is because the loop doesn't run fully. When you use return, it returns the value, which exits the function. The rest of the loop never executes.

What you want instead is to return an array. The easiest way is probably a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def tabellina(n):
    return [n*i for i in range(11)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could save the output in a string and then return that. for example:

```
def tabellina(n):
   table = ''
   for i in range (1,11):
       table += ((n*i) + ' ')
   return table
```

you could replace `' '` with any devider (like `','`) as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script:

```
def tabellina(n):
   joint = ""
   for i in range (1,11):
       joint = joint + (" %s" % n*i)
   return joint
```